# How to Get the data after the @ sign from an email using php

Tags: php, forms, validation

i am trying to get the data After an '@' sign from an email address, 
this is what i am trying to do i am using the $_GET['email'] to get the email from the url, now i want to extract the data after the @, store the data in a variable then send the user to that domain eg: email@gmail.com i want to get the gmail.com, store it and then send the user to gmail.com

this is all i have tried but all gives me the same error
1:

```
    $domain1 = $_GET['email'];    
    $domain = substr($domain1, strpos($domain1, "@") + 1); 
    // then am using the header location to send the user to the gmail.com
    header('Location: http://$domain');
```

2:

```
       $domain1 = $_GET['email'];
       $domain2 = strtok( $domain1, '@' );
       $domain = strtok( '' ); 
       // then am using the header location to send the user to the gmail.com
       header('Location: http://$domain');
```

this is the error

```
This site can’t be reached %24domain’s server IP address could not be found.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

if you read the error message it is trying to redirect to %24domain and i don't know where its getting that from

i have tried all the Technics related to this i saw from this forum but i still get the same error

guys please help

Comment: Change your quotes to double quotes: `header("Location: http://$domain");`

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to accomplish here? Why redirect users to their email's domain?